# How To Change desktops focus automatically

Tags: macos, spaces

Sometimes when switching between spaces/desktops I notice the app I switched to does not have the focus, but rather a previous window/desktop/space that I had just been interacting with.

For example if I switch from one space to a browser, and close a tab with the keyboard, a tab in the previous space closes, and I have to click on the window in front of me for it to gain focus. This isn't a problem with animation speed as the key presses can happen 20-30 seconds after switching. It also happens when switching spaces with both keyboard and trackpad shortcuts ( ctrl+arrow and 4 finger swipes )

Is there a timer I can adjust to change when focus changes? Is this a setting?

Note that I'm happy with the animation speed, and I'm aware of other methods of switching applications such as cmd+tab, I'm not asking about those.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if the Space you are switching to also has a window from the app you just moved away from. Spaces has never liked apps spread to more than one Space. Otherwise if should front the last app used in that new Space.